# Facing Issue with RenderedItem.AddBinary method which is deleting the existing Binaries

Tags: tom.net, 2013-sp1-hr1, template-building-blocks

I am using below lines of code to add the binary in my  CT :

```
Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.Binary binary = TridionHelper.Engine.PublishingContext.RenderedItem.AddBinary(component);
return binary.Url
```

I get the result of URL as

```
“/Images/sample_tcm2-192851.jpg”.
```

However, the image name is **“sample.jpg”**, which means the AddBinary method is adding the default variant as TCM- Id of the Image Component (correct me if my understanding is wrong).
The image gets published successfully at the above location, hence no problem so far.

But what I have noticed is that in another CT, we are referring the same image component as below:

```
<img src="@Fields.Image" alt="@Fields.alt" >
```

This works fine when we publish the page and generates the URL as `“/Images/sample.jpg”` as expected, but deletes or un-publish the above image i.e. “sample_tcm2-192851.jpg” which results in the broken image in another page.

Am I missing something while using the method AddBinary?

Thanks.